# Adding a link tag to a masterpage with mvc 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

```
foreach (var item in ((ModelBase)Model).Stylesheets)
{ %>
  <%=item.url %>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= Url.Content(item.url)%>" />
<% }
```

I've got the code above running but whenever it outputs the link tag I get the following.

```
../../Content/Site.css<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Views/Shared/%3C%25=%20Url.Content(item.url)%25%3E" />
```

I'm confused cause the item.url is outputting the correct value, and if I type the value in manually it's ok, but using item.url inside the url.content function causes the above to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the head tag was runat server.

Answer (score 0):

What about just

```
foreach (var item in ((ModelBase)Model).Stylesheets)
{ %>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=item.url %>" />
<% }
```

Depending on how you create the url property in your model, Url.Content is probably having trouble resolving it. Why not just reference it like this?

**Edit:** Sorry this doesn't really answer WHY your problem is happening, but instead just gives a work around if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Doing as you suggested output's the following. <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Views/Shared/%3C%25=item.url%20%25%3E" />

Comment: That's weird. So it's the same problem. Are you sure your <% and %> tags are all opened and closed properly?

Comment: if i stick @ infront of the href attribute all is well, remove and back to the problem. I'm a little confused.